# phpunit clase declarada como final no se puede mockear

Tags: php, phpunit, testing

tengo el siguiente método en un handler de mi aplicación:

```
public function __invoke(FoodQuery $food) : BeerListResponse
{
    $apiResponse = $this->repository->searchByCriteria($food);
    $beerlist = $this->beerListCreator->createBeerList($apiResponse);
    return new BeerListResponse($beerlist);
}
```

tanto el `repository` como el `beerListCreator` están mockeados en el test:

```
    $food = new FoodQuery('meal');
    $repository = $this->createMock(BeerRepositoryInterface::class);
    $repository
        ->method('searchByCriteria')
        ->with($food)
        ->willReturn([]);
    $creator = $this->createMock(CreateBeerlistFromApi::class);
    $creator
        ->method('createBeerList')
        ->with([]);
    $handler = new GetBeerListHandler($repository, $creator);
    $response = $handler->__invoke($food);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(BeerListResponse::class, $response);
```

Lo que intento probar en este test es únicamente que cuando se invoque al handler, se llame al método `CreateBeerListFromApi` del repository, y al método `createBeerList` del CreateBeerListFromApi.

el problema se me presenta cuando se llama al método `createBeerList`, pues este método me devuelve un objeto tipo `BeerList`:

```
public function createBeerList(array $list): BeerList
{
    $beerList = new BeerList();
    foreach($list as $item) {
        $beerList->addBeer($this->beerCreator->createBeer($item));
    }
    return $beerList;
}
```

y el error que obtengo al pasar los test es:

```
There was 1 error:

1) App\Tests\Application\Handler\GetBeerListHandlerTest::it_should_gave_a_valid_beer_list
PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ClassIsFinalException: Class "App\Domain\Entity\BeerList" is
declared "final" and cannot be mocked
```

Efectivamente, la clase `BeerList` es de tipo `final`:

```
/**
 * Class BeerList
 * @package App\Domain\Entity
 */
final class BeerList
{ ...
```

Entiendo que con quitar el `final` es suficiente, y ya no tengo errores de test (Lo he comprobado, lo soluciona). Pero la pregunta es si hay alguna manera de poder testear esto (no en todos los casos se podrá quitar el final, por ej, si la clase fuera de un vendor de la app...

Alguien se le ocurre como podría pasar este test teniendo `final` en la clase? me he olvidado algo?

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, revisa [este post](https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2019/03/28/how-to-mock-final-classes-in-phpunit/) y también [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32213542/5587982) y sus respuestas.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano, siempre estas por aqui :) El tema es que yo como tal no quiero mockear ninguna de las clases finales. Lo que quiero es testear el handler, y solo evaluar que se llaman los metodos... sigo mirando los enlaces a ver si saco algo, gracias :)

Comment: @Jakala La solución pasa por desacoplarte de la infraestructura, es decir de la implementación concreta del repositorio, tu lógica no debería conocer el repositorio específico, para hacerlo deberías añadir un punto de indireccion mediante una interfaz. Tu repositorio implementará está interfaz también. Para el test puedes mokear la interfaz o crear una implementación fake que implemente dicha interfaz.

Comment: @Xerif como dices, eso es cierto. No he puesto el constructor de la clase handler, pero efectivamente ahí pido un interfaz, para desacoplar la infraestructura. En la config del servicio es donde realmente inyectamos un servicio de infraestructura que cumple el interfaz. Como pongo en la pregunta, el test mockea la interfaz del repositorio. El servicio, al ser de aplicación, debería también tener un interfaz para mockearlo también?

Comment: Al no ver los `use` ni `namespace` es un poco difícil apreciar a que capa pertenece cada cosa. `CreateBeerlistFromApi` por el nombre suena a infraestructura. Lo que veo que, parte del problema es por qué `BeerList` en el método `createBeerList` es una dependencia oculta. En cualquier caso, considero que más que una interfaz de aplicación/servicio o un moock, por qué no instanciar directamente `CreateBeerlistFromApi`? Intuyo lo que quieres hacer pero sin ver la implementación...